Indentation in tables / fine control over hlines
I would like to achieve an effect that can best be described as "indentation in tables." Consider the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{l r}\text{We have:} & \text{To show:}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l}{\text{\textbf{Case:} $K = \bullet$}}&\multicolumn{1}{r}{\mathit{IM}(\bullet)}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\hspace{5em}\text{Choosing $B := A$, we show $\vdash K : A \Rightarrow A ~\land~ \vdash e : A$}}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\hspace{5em}\text{Split the cases}}\\
    %everything from here should be indented, including the `\hline`.
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\hspace{5em}\vdash K : A \Rightarrow A}\\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\vdash e' : A}&\multicolumn{1}{r}{\vdash \bullet[e'] : A}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\hspace{5em}\text{Done by assumption}}
\end{array}\]
\end{document}

It currently looks like this:

But I would want it to look like this (achieved using an image editor):

Notice that after the "split the cases,"  the left side is "indented" and no longer flush with the left edge of the table.
So, I thought a bit about how to go about this. Indenting the text itself is not hard--you just add several \quads before it, until you reach the wanted level of indentation.
But I have no clue about how you should indent the \hline.
So the actual question I mean to ask is "how do you make a \hline have an arbitrary gap at the start/end," or perhaps even "can you make a \hline that is dashed and has a gap"?
But the actual problem I am trying to solve is that of indented tables. If there's a way of achieving this that does not require "indenting an \hline," I am happy to have that as well.
And besides the \hline, if there is a vertical line (like before the initial "Case K = •"), that should also be indented, if possible.
Thanks!

Like This? With tabularray
With an additional column. The indentation is given with ,wd=15pt in the first column.
EDIT2: with \SetVline{\arabic{rownum}}{} for the vline "inline" BUT with an additional column for the vertical line in "last column". With Q[leftsep=0pt,rightsep=0pt], we "no longer see" this added column.
\SetVline{\arabic{rownum}}{}

Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
% \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent\hfil\begin{tblr}{
    width   = 0.95\linewidth,
    colspec = { Q[l,wd=15pt] X[l] X[r,mode=math] Q[leftsep=0pt,rightsep=0pt]},   
    row{1}  = {mode=text},
    % hline{2},
    % hline{5} = {2-3}{solid},
    %vline{1} = {2}{solid},
    %vline{4} = {5}{solid},
    }
\SetCell[c=2]{l}We have:&&To show:\\ \cline{1-3}%<-- Don't forget &&
\SetVline{\arabic{rownum}}{}
\SetCell[c=2]{l}\textbf{Case: }$K=\bullet$  
    &&IM(\bullet)\\%<--
    &\SetCell[c=2]{r}Choosing  $B := A$, we show $\vdash K : A \Rightarrow A ~\land~ \vdash e : A$\\
    &\SetCell[c=2]{r}Split the cases\\\cline{2-3}
    &&\vdash K : A \Rightarrow A&\SetVline{\arabic{rownum}}{}\\%<-- vline in enew column
    &$\vdash e' : A$ &\vdash \bullet[e'] : A\\
    &\SetCell[c=2]{r}Done by assumption
\end{tblr}%
\end{document}



That looks promising, I'll see if I can patch that into the existing macros

Is it possible to do the h- and vlines "inline" instead of specifying them in the header? Putting them there is quite fragile since you need to change all the numbers if you (say) add a line at the top.

For horizontal lines, it's simple with \hline or \cline as with tabular, but for vertical lines?

With \SetVline{\arabic{rownum}}{} for the vline see EDIT2
